# Assign a process to a string?

Tags: c#, string, process

How can I assign a process to a string? I use this:

```
Process[] all = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process thisProc in all)
{
    Name = thisProc.ProcessName;
}
```

Result:

```
Name = audiodg.exe
```

Eventually it comes out with only the first process, but I want to assign the values to string 1,2,3 all processes requiring.

example:

```
Name1 = google.exe
Name2 = note.exe
Name3 = .......exe
Name4 = .......exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of collection, like a `List<string>` or `Array`. In this case, an `IEnumerable<string>` might be good enough. We can do it like this:

```
var Names = Process.GetProcesses().Select(p => p.ProcessName);
```

If you really need a numbered index, just put a `.ToList()` on the end of that.

Comment: @gunr2171 Ooops. I randomly just ran into 3 vb.Net questions in a row, and it was in my head that way. Fixed in a moment.

Comment: oh, yeah, i figured that's what it was. +1